# Perl generating hash of complex records

Tags: arrays, perl, output

The big problem that I can't seem to figure out.
I need to input into this complex hash (array?):

```
my $raterequest =  
{
    Shipment =>
    {
        Shipper =>
        {
            (static data here)
        },
        ShipTo =>
        {
            (static data here too)
        },
        Package =>
        [
            {
                PackagingType =>
                {
                    Code => '02',
                    Description => 'Package'
                },
                PackageWeight =>
                {
                    UnitOfMeasurement =>
                    {
                        Code => 'LBS'
                    },
                    Weight => $boxWt
                },
            },

            {
                PackagingType =>
                {
                    Code => '02',
                    Description => 'Package'
                },
                PackageWeight =>
                {
                    UnitOfMeasurement =>
                    {
                        Code => 'LBS'
                    },
                    Weight => $boxWt
                },
            }
        ],
    }
};
```

What I need to input is everything inside the `Package` array.

I have an LoH that generates an output like this:

```
my %carton_specs = 
    (
        25 => {
            boxQty  =>  25,
            boxWt   =>  4,
            boxNo   =>  2
        },
        50 => {
            boxQty  =>  50,
            boxWt   =>  8,
            boxNo   =>  17
        },
);
```

Where I need to repeat the anonymous array inside `Package`

```
{
    PackagingType =>
    {
        Code => '02',
        Description => 'Package'
    },
    PackageWeight =>
    {
        UnitOfMeasurement =>
        {
            Code => 'LBS'
        },
        Weight => $boxWt
    },
},
```

times the number returned from `$boxNo`.  The only variable that changes in that is the `Weight => $boxWt`

Please excuse anything that I might have named wrong.  I have been fighting with this for 2 days and my head is exploding.

Comment: how do you know if you need it repeated $carton_specs{25}{boxNo} times or $carton_specs{50}{boxNo} times?

Comment: it needs to iterate through both loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are looking for [`push`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) plus the information from [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) (plus maybe the [`..` range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators)). I hope I understood your specifications correctly:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dump;

my $raterequest = {
    Shipment => {
        Package => [ ],
    } };

my %carton_specs =  (
    25 => { boxQty => 25, boxWt => 4, boxNo =>  2 },
    50 => { boxQty => 50, boxWt => 8, boxNo => 17 },
);

for my $carton (sort keys %carton_specs) {
    for ( 1 .. $carton_specs{$carton}{boxNo} ) {
        push @{ $raterequest->{Shipment}{Package} }, {
            PackagingType => {
                Code => '02',
                Description => 'Package',
            },
            PackageWeight => {
                UnitOfMeasurement => { Code => 'LBS' },
                Weight => $carton_specs{$carton}{boxWt},
            },
        };
    }
}

dd $raterequest;
```

Output:

```
{
  Shipment => {
    Package => [
      {
        PackageWeight => { UnitOfMeasurement => { Code => "LBS" }, Weight => 4 },
        PackagingType => { Code => "02", Description => "Package" },
      },
      {
        PackageWeight => { UnitOfMeasurement => { Code => "LBS" }, Weight => 4 },
        PackagingType => { Code => "02", Description => "Package" },
      },
      {
        PackageWeight => { UnitOfMeasurement => { Code => "LBS" }, Weight => 8 },
        PackagingType => { Code => "02", Description => "Package" },
      },
      # ... omit 16 repetitions of the previous hashref ...
    ],
  },
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!! Thank you so much for the quick response!  I just got done getting a 20 min lecture from my boss about how we should have hired someone to do this because I obviously can't figure it out.  Lets just ignore the part where I knew nothing of Perl 4 days ago, taught myself Perl, and learned as much of the nuances as I could sort out while trying to write a sub and implement at the same time!  again, THANK YOU!!!

Comment: And now that i'm looking at the final code, push seems so obvious!